# Is $¬r→q = r \vee q$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I know that by conversion theorem, $ r → q = \lnot r \vee q $. So if $¬r → q$ will be equal to $r \vee q$ and not $r \vee ¬q$ right?

Let's say we know that $q$ and $p$ are true. Given that $ r → s; ¬r → q; p \vee r;$ are true.

How do we know that whether $r$ is true or false?

Comment: `\vee` instead of `v`

Comment: (1) Yes $(\neg r)\implies q$ is equivalent to $r\vee q$ and this statement is different and unequivalent to $r\vee \neg q$.  (2) Suppose $r,q,p$ and your three other statements are all true.  No contradictions with your hypotheses.  Suppose $\neg r, q, p$ and your three other statements are true.  Still no contradictions.  Ergo, we don't know then whether $r$ is true or false.

Comment: What if there is a conclusion (p∨q)Λr, so is this argument valid? Can we prove by contradiction method?

Comment: If $(p\vee q)\wedge r$ is said to be true that implies that both $(p\vee q)$ is true and $r$ is true., which in particular implies that $r$ is true...

Comment: If you are asking whether the given hypotheses imply that $(p\vee q)\wedge r$ is true, no they do not.  Consider the situation where $p,q,\neg r, s$ are all true.  The hypotheses are all true then but the conclusion is false.

Comment: hmm cause I realize that r can be both true and false. if r is false, the conditions given above are still true; if r is true, s must be true since  r→s is a true statement. Therefore I'm not sure that the argument(conclusion) is valid or invalid.

Comment: "*The argument*"  What argument... you haven't provided one.  Regardless... considering $p,q,\neg r, s$ and the three other hypothetical statements listed in the question, we have the conclusion $(p\vee q)\wedge r$ is false., meanwhile if we consider $p,q,r,s$ and the three other hypothetical statements listed in the question, we have the conclusion above is instead true.  As a result with the given hypotheses both outcomes are possible and *any* argument which attempts to prove that the conclusion is either true or attempts to prove the conclusion is false must be flawed and invalid.

Comment: The argument is the conclusion which is (p∨q)∧r. By the way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$\begin{array}\\
\lnot\ r\implies q\\
p\ \lor\ r\\
\hline
(r\ \lor\ q)\ \land (p\ \lor\ r)
\end{array}$$

Since you said $p$ and $q$ are true, whether or not $r$ is true is not important/ it won't affect the truth of the conclusion/ it's unknown/ it can be either.

And in your title it's $\large\lnot\ r\implies q \color{blue}{\equiv} r\ \lor\ q$, not $\color{red}{=}$.

---

If you want to prove that $r$ is false, try to find $t$ s.t.

$$\begin{array}\\
r\implies t\\
t\ \land\ s\equiv\bot\ ,\\
\end{array}$$

which $\bot$ means a contradiction, then

$$\begin{array}\\
r\implies s\\
r\implies t\\
t\ \land\ s\equiv\bot\\
\hline
\lnot\ r
\end{array}$$